# How do I change the shared components, tools, and SDKs path in VisualStudio Community2022 since there is no VisualStudio directory in my registry

Tags: windows, visual-studio, registry

I am new to learning the C++ renderer engine and I need to install some workloads and components in Visual Studio 2022, I would like to install them in my E drive but it seems that VS2022 doesn't allow me to change the location where they are installed (I have installed them once before)

[image]

I searched for a solution on Google and tried [Mircosoft QA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/748324/vs-enterprise-2022-how-can-i-change-installation-p) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/130ormf/cant_change_the_shared_components_tools_and_sdks/) ways to solve.

But I found that there is no Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft directory in my registry editor.

[image]

I don't know how to fix this.BTW my OS is Windows 11 Home Edition

I tried the method on Google to allow the path to be changed by modifying the registry, but there doesn't seem to be a directory specified in the other posts in the registry editor.

Comment: What happens if you open `regedit` with elevated privileges? Can you navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft` ? If not, are there any results when searching the registry for `Microsoft` and limiting that search to keys (values and data are unticked / unchecked).